# Java protocol design

Tags: java, tcp, rfc

Im planning to deploy a version for some IETF drafts and need some code references or guidance. Im familiar with basic TCP sockets but want to know how to translate requirements into code.

Example: [Format for the Session Initiation Protocol (SIP) Common Log Format (CLF)](http://tools.ietf.org/id/draft-salgueiro-sipclf-indexed-ascii-03.txt)

Would like to see how to translate:

```
 0          7 8        15 16       23 24         31
  +-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
  |  Version  |           Record Length           | 0 - 3
  +-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+

   Version (1 byte):  0x41 for this document; hexadecimal encoded.

   Record Length (6 bytes):  Hexadecimal encoded total length of this
  log record, including "Flags" and "Record Length" fields, and
  terminating line-feed.
```

into code.
How can I define Version?
Which type?
Int, char, etc?

Thanks

Comment: Well, as any data type that is at least 1 byte long.

Comment: You have `Record Length (6 bytes)` but in the diagram it looks like 24bits(3bytes)

Comment: @Musa, click on the link to the IETF draft, the ASCII art continues on the next line to show the other 3 bytes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of writing it from scratch, I would suggest to use applications like [Jboss Netty](https://netty.io/) , [Apache Mina](http://mina.apache.org/) or [Grizzly](http://grizzly.java.net/). They are specifically targeted for high performance protocol development.

[Here is an example](http://jfarcand.wordpress.com/2008/02/12/writing-a-tcpudp-stack-supporting-the-sip-protocol-using-the-grizzly-framework/) of Grizzly being used for Supporting SIP.

Answer (score 2):

Your primary tool will be `DataOutputStream`. It handles all the primitive types and takes care of network byte ordering for you as well. `DataInputStream` at the receiver. Your `Version` field would be written with `write()`.

Answer (score 2):

You'll run into some problems because Java doesn't include any unsigned types, you might also run into issues with endianness (Java is always big-endian). If a protocol specification stipulates that a 16-bit unsigned integer field exists then you'd hold the value in a 32-bit signed integer and write out (or read) the raw bytes to/from Network streams on a per-byte basis. Note that InputStream's `read()` method returns individual bytes as `int` values.

Here's how I'd read your example:

```
InputStream stream = getNetworkInputStream();
int version = stream.read();

int recordLength0 = stream.read();
int recordLength1 = stream.read();
int recordLength2 = stream.read();
int recordLength3 = stream.read();

long recordLength = recordLength0 << 24 | recordLength1 << 16 | recordLength2 << 8 | recordLength; // perform the bitwise OR of all four values
```

Writing is slightly more painful. Be careful if you do use the `byte` type internally as it is signed.

```
int version; long recordLength;

OutputStream stream = getNetworkOutputStream();
stream.write( version ); // the write(int) method only writes the low 8 bits of the integer value and ignores the high 24 bits.

stream.write( recordLength >> 24 ); // shift the recordLength value to the right by 8 bits
stream.write( recordLength >> 16 );
stream.write( recordLength >>  8 );
stream.write( recordLength       );
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [ByteBuffer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html) for converting the bytes into individual variables.  It can deal with byte order for you.